# What is the best way to manage configurations in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I have an app that has a lot of api keys and setting to be managed and they are loaded using an initializer. BEcause they are different for each environment, I can't set a constant in the environment.rb file. (I tried that; didn't work.) So I started comment-and-uncomment by hand before every deployment, which is tedious. I'm wondering what would be a best practice for a situation where you have to deal with multiple configuration settings loaded in an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

In your environment.rb you can set your keys if the request is coming from local:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config| 
    if local_request?
       CONSTANT1 = 10
    else
       CONSTANT1 = 20
    end 
end
```

What this will do is check if you are on `localhost` which is `localhost:3000`, your development environment. If so then the if/else statement will pick which constant to set.

another option would be to set the constants in your environments folder which is probably a better idea

so for your production constants put them in `config/environments/production.rb`.

and for your development constants put them in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: Are we the only two answering RoR questions tonight? :P

Comment: What do you think about splitting these into environments/dev.rb and environments/prod.rb? It wouldn't pollute the global config file.

Comment: lol, I guess it's just us. I agree. Probably be better for organization.

Comment: Can you explain what this would do? And by variables do you mean constants? I didn't realize you could set global variable values (in smallcase).

Comment: I thought this would work, but I still get config/initializers/omniauth.rb:4: uninitialized constant errors from one of the initializers, which is defined in a block like this: Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do ... end

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting these constants in initializer files, which you can create under the initializer directory. Then, use the environment-specific config files that are under the environments directory to set them per environment.